# Replace content with jQuery.fn.load

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write a client script to use .load in a non-typical way. I'm working with another site and I don't have access to change their generated code, so I have to do everything on the client side.

The page looks something like

```
<html>
  <!-- the head -->
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <!-- the content -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to update the page with an XHR. I want to replace the contents of `#body` with the new contents of `#body` from the XHR. My first instinct was to do this:

```
$('#body').load('/ #body')
```

But that gives me a DOM that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <!-- the head -->
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="body">
        <!-- the content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's clearly not what I want. I want `<!-- the content -->` from the newly fetched copy to just overwrite `<!-- the content -->` from the current copy.

I have also tried things along the lines of

```
$.get('/', function(data) {
  $('#body').html($(data).find('#body').html());
}
```

to no avail. When I play with it, I find that `$(data).find('#body')` never finds anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the result of your XHR, assuming it is html in a jquery object, grab the body of the calling page and use replaceWith.

```
//snip
var xhrResult = $("<html><div id='body'>blah</div></html>"), // pretend this was returned
    newContent = xhrResult.filter("#body"),
    placeHere = $("#body");
placeHere.replaceWith(newContent);
```

Edited Based on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/VmhBW/

Comment: This definitely occurred to me. However, wrapping the response in `$()` is not giving me a useful jQuery object. For instance $(data).find('#body') yields nothing, but if I examine the object in my JavaScript console, I can see a `<div id="body">` in there.

Comment: The problem here is that the only way that I can retrieve just the part of the page that I want seems to be with `.load`. I can't get anything less than the whole page assigned to a variable. A callback function fed to `.load` also precludes a selector after the URL; the `function(data) data` variable ends up holding the whole response.

Comment: "if I examine the object" - which object? data? Is data an object or is it a string of HTML? If it is not HTML, wrapping it in a jquery object won't do any good.

Comment: It's HTML. If you're really interested in checking it out, I'd recommend playing with some examples on http://jsfiddle.net. :) I _do_ read the docs before I ask a question on SO.

Comment: Sorry if I came off sounding that way. I _am_ interested and will put together a fiddle later on this evening, as I would like to help solve the problem. Especially for someone who reads the docs :)

Comment: OK, had a break in the schedule. Fiddle added. Updated answer to reflect fiddle, it looks like jquery is creating a jquery object when you pass it a string of HTML, so I used $.fn.filter to call out the element that we're after. Hope this helps.

Comment: `.filter` was my savior! I've been trying to use `.find` for this purpose. I will read more to understand why that doesn't work, but it looks like `$.get('/', function(data) { $('#body').html($(data).filter('#body').html()); });` gets the job done perfectly!

(I didn't think you were being condescending or anything. Thanks very much for your help!)